# What does Interpretation by Vikram Seth mean?

Tags: meaning, poetry

In the poetry collection *[All You Who Sleep Tonight](https://books.google.com/books?id=MEeM3szw1-8C&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56#v=onepage&q&f=false)* by Vikram Seth, is this four-line poem entitled Interpretation:

> Somewhere within your loving look I sense,
>
> Without the least intention to deceive,
>
> Without suspicion, without evidence,
>
> Somewhere within your heart the heart to leave.

What is the meaning of this poem?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U.  It is not clear what you are asking for.  Is your interest a matter of vocabulary or syntax? Are you looking for a literary interpretation, or perhaps a paraphrase?  Your question may be off-topic, or it may need sharpening.  Refer to the [help](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) section for guidance on posing good questions.

Comment: Hello.  I have made some edits to *help* improve this question, but you will need to edit it further to be on-topic.  Interpreting an entire poem, even a short one like this, is beyond the scope of this site.  Is there a specific word or phrase that gives you trouble, for example?

Answer (score 1):

English has a number of tropes to convey the emotion of love by bodily description.  One of these is to place the seat of emotion in the heart.  You "give your heart" to a lover, and the one you love "breaks your heart" by spurning you.  Other descriptions use the senses, e.g., "the look of love."  For instance, consider the lyrics to the song of the same name:

> The **look** of love is in your eyes
>   The **look**, your smile can't disguise
>   The **look** of love, it's saying so much more
>   Than just words could ever say
>   And what my **heart** has **heard**, well it
>   takes my breath away

Here the beloved conveys the emotion of her love by seeing him in a certain way, a way that he, in turn, can see for himself.  (Notice that the heart is here too, a heart that can hear.)

Let's examine just the first and last lines of the poem:

> Somewhere within your loving look I sense,
>   ...
>   Somewhere within your heart the heart to leave.

The insecure lover sees that look of love, but he detects somehow that she might leave him anyway.  *Heart* not only metaphorically conveys the feeling of love, but also strength and courage.  In other words, the wherewithal to leave him.

Now, the second line:

> Without the least intention to deceive,

The insecure lover isn't making an accusation of deceit; he doesn't think his beloved is concealing her desire to leave.

And the third line:

> Without suspicion, without evidence,

The insecure lover isn't made suspicious by any actual evidence he can cite, but in spite of that he knows somehow that his beloved is capable of throwing him over.

(The gender of my pronouns is heterosexist for convenience.  Feel free to transpose them to any other relationships.)

Answer (score 0):

He is able to perceive her latent desire to leave after all, despite absence of such physical manifestations.